# Mapping a searchable localized field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing a product catalog that has a searchable `title` field, but that title needs to be localized in different languages so `title_en`, `title_de`, `title_fr` etc. The title can be localized in any language.

Instead of defining a mapping for each localized version, can I use regex to manifest this localized field, so basically `title_*`. This is because we are importing the catalog, and we don't know upfront what all languages will we receive the title in.

Comment: The problem with a [regex dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-pattern) is how are you going to apply [language specific analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to Elasticsearch, so good to know.